# How to sum the values from same index from multiple lists within multiple lists?

Tags: python, list, sum

I have a list that contains multiple lists which at the same time, those lists contain multiple lists. For simplicity lets say I have:

```
x = [
    [[1, 0], [0, 0], [0 , 0], [1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
    ]
```

Lets consider the following variable:

```
y = [[0, 0], [0, 2], [0 , 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1]]
```

Is there a more pythonic way to obtain:

```
res = [[1, 0], [0, 2], [0 , 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0], [0, 1]]
```

Other than:

```
for i in range(len(y)):
    res.append([y[i][0] + x[0][i][0], y[i][1] + x[0][i][1]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions and do t in 1 line:

```
x_list = x[0]  # Not sure why x is inside a list but I'm going with it
result = [[sum(subitmes) for subitems in zip(*items)] for items in zip(x_list, y)]
```

Comment: x[0] is inside a list because x contains multiple lists as x[0]